# Overriding the process() Method in SwingWorker

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, process

I'm trying to dynamically update the GUI with a `String`.  Can anyone see why the process method is not overriding correctly?  I've looked at other questions and still cannot see how I am not overriding this correctly.

```
public class WorkerDemo extends JFrame {

private JLabel counterLabel = new JLabel("Not started");
private Worker worker = new Worker();
private JButton startButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Start") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            worker = new Worker();
            worker.execute();
    }
});
private JButton stopButton = new JButton(new AbstractAction("Stop") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        worker.cancel(true);
    }
});

public WorkerDemo() {

    add(startButton, BorderLayout.WEST);
    add(counterLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(stopButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
    pack();
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setVisible(true);
}

class Worker extends SwingWorker<Void, Integer> {

    int counter = 0;
    String abc = "abc";

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
        while(true) {
            abc += abc; 
            publish(abc);
            Thread.sleep(60);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Object> chunk) {
        // get last result
        String to_return = (String) chunk.get(chunk.size()-1);

        counterLabel.setText(to_return);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new WorkerDemo();
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: A single blank line of white space in source code is all that is *ever* needed.  Blank lines after `{` or before `}` are also typically redundant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you have `SwingWorker<Void, Integer>`, you have defined `Integer` as a type to carry out intermediate results by publish and process methods. That means proper `publish()` and `process()` methods should use `Integer`:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
    int someResult = 0;
    ...
    publish(someResult);
    ...
 }


@Override
protected void process(List<Integer> chunk) {
}
```

See [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) for more details.